# Double check locking of class member in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

Is it correct to use double check locking with not static fields?

```
class Foo
{ 
   private SomeType member;
   private readonly object memeberSync = new object();
   public SomeType Memeber
   { 
      get
      {
         if(member == null)
         { 
            lock(memeberSync)
            {
               if(member == null)
               {
                  member = new SomeType();
               } 
            }
         }
         return object;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you *actually* trying to implement the singleton pattern? If so, there are clearer patterns. See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Answer (score 6):

> Is it correct to use double check locking with not static fields?

Yes, nothing wrong with your code to use double checking with `lock` to get *thread-safe* and *lazy loading*. If you are using from .NET 4, it would be suggested using [Lazy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx) class, this approach get the same result with *thread-safe* and *lazy loading* but it also  makes your code simpler, more readable.

```
class Foo
{
    private readonly Lazy<SomeType> _member = 
                                   new Lazy<SomeType>(() => new SomeType());

    public SomeType Member
    {
        get { return _member.Value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The outer check gives a performance boost in that, once `member` is initialised, you don't have to obtain the lock every time you access the property.  If you're accessing the property frequently from multiple threads, the performance hit of the lock could be quite noticeable.

The inner check is necessary to prevent race conditions: without that, it would be possible for two threads to process the outer `if` statement, and then both would initialise `member`.

Strictly speaking, the outer `if` isn't *necessary*, but it's considered good practise and (in a heavily-threaded application) the performance benefit would be noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

It is a practice recommended by some because your lock may not apply until another lock is released.

In this case two threads access the getter at the same time, the first one gets the lock and the second waits.

Once the first is finished, the second thread now has the lock.

In cases where this is possible, you should check to see if the variable has already been created by another thread before the current thread acquired lock.